# get missing dates from a date column in a table darby apache db

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a table name as 'h1' with field as 'date'. How do I get missing dates in this table using Darby query

DATA IN TABLE h1

```
   date
   ------------
   2018-03-10
   2018-03-11
   2018-03-13
   2018-03-14
   2018-03-16
```

Expected Result is `missing dates: 2018-03-12 ,2018-03-15`

I've tried every thing on blogs but nothing found properly working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a query, something like this might work.

```
SELECT sq.nextday AS missingday
FROM
  (SELECT date1.dates AS currentdate,
          date1.dates + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS nextday,
          date2.dates AS actualnextday
   FROM h1 date1
   LEFT JOIN h1 date2 ON date2.dates = date1.dates + INTERVAL 1 DAY) sq
WHERE sq.actualnextday IS NULL HAVING max(sq.currentdate) > sq.nextday;
```

Comment: Not Working in apache db

Comment: You tagged your question for mysql.

Comment: i am not have much repo for tag darby